# JList - add scroll button

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlist, jscrollbar

I have `JList` code that I want to add to a scroll button on the side since the list is longer than the text box window.
    that's the code:

```
final JList list = new JList();
        list.setBounds(36, 23, 366, 241);
        contentPane.add(list);
File folder = new File(FILETOSTART);
                        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

                        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
                            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                                System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
                                list.setListData(listOfFiles);                              
                            } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
                                System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    in.close();
                }
                catch (Exception exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
```

How can I add this scroll side button?

Comment: 1) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

If by 'button' you mean 'scroll bar' then it can be<sup>1</sup> as simple as:

```
contentPane.add(new JScrollPane(list));
```

Instead of:

```
contentPane.add(list);
```

1. Except when using absolute positioning, as seems might be the case here.

Comment: I tried to add it but it didnt work... I wanted to use this object - JScrollBar

Comment: *"I tried to add it but it didnt work..."* 1) What do you expect us to do about that when you have not posted an MCVE/SSCCE as I suggested in my 2nd comment? Read both documents. 2) But the reason it did not work is most likely revealed in my first comment - using `null` layouts. 3) *"I wanted to use this object - JScrollBar"* Yes, a `JScrollPane` usually includes a vertical scroll bar for a `JList`, but it needs to work with **layout managers** to do its job properly.